# Swift- How do I choose what cells go into what section (UITableView)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made this:

```
var data = ["Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry",
    "Clementine", "Coconut", "Cranberry", "Fig", "Grape", "Grapefruit",
    "Kiwi fruit", "Lemon", "Lime", "Lychee", "Mandarine", "Mango",
    "Melon", "Nectarine", "Olive", "Orange", "Papaya", "Peach",
    "Pear", "Pineapple", "Raspberry", "Strawberry"]
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 12
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return data.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellLabel", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return months[section]
}
```

Now how do I choose what variables in my data array go into which "month" section? Is there a method I should use that I'm unaware of?
(This is in a class that extends UITableView)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` and `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` have section and indexPath arguments, indexPath has `section` variable. So basically you should do some switch statements in these functions to return desired data based on the month. It might be a better idea to have an array of data for each month. Or multidimensional array, or even some custom datatype.
Anyways, the code might be something like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return dataJanuary.count
    }
    else if section == 1 {
        return dataFebruary.count
    }
    // ...
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellLabel", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataJanuary[indexPath.row]
    }
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataFebruary[indexPath.row]
    }
    // ...
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for the clarification. I knew that I wanted to make some sort of key-value datatype, but had no clue what method controlled placement. Thanks a ton!